# How to take 2 argument from getopts

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I am creating a bash script that will two argument from the user from command line . But i am not sure how I can take 2 argument from the user and both arguments are required if not passed will show error and return from the script . Below is the code i am using to take argument from the user , but currently my getopts is taking only one argument.

```
optspec="h-:"
while getopts "$optspec" optchar; do
  case "${optchar}" in
    -)
      case "$OPTARG" in
        file)
          display_usage ;;
        file=*)
          INPUTFILE=${OPTARG#*=};;
      esac;;
    h|*) display_usage;;
  esac
done
```

How could i add an an option to take one more args from command line. Like below

```
script.sh --file="abc" --date="dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: @chepner i want to do something like this script.sh --file="abc" --date="dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: `getopts` doesn't do long options, either.

Comment: If both arguments are required, don't make them options (starting with `-`), make them positional parameters.

Comment: @chepner could you please suggest how we can do it from getopt

Comment: Why use this syntax at all?  You could write zero code and invoke the script as `file=abc date=dd/mm/yy script.sh`.  If you want to parse arguments, invoke the script as `script.sh file=abc date=dd/mm/yy`.  The extra `--` provide no additional value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getopts` does not support long arguments. It only supports single letter arguments.

You can use [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html). It is not as widely available as `getopts`, which is from posix and available everywhere.  `getopt` will be for sure available on any linux and not only. On linux it's part of `linux-utils`, a group of most basic utilities like `mount` or `swapon`.

Typical `getopt` usage looks like:

```
if ! args=$(getopt -n "your_script_name" -oh -l file:,date: -- "$@"); then
    echo "Error parsing arguments" >&2
    exit 1
fi
# getopt parses `"$@"` arguments and generates a nice looking string
# getopt .... -- arg1 --file=file arg2 --date=date arg3
# would output:
# --file file --date date -- arg1 arg2 arg3
# the idea is to re-read bash arguments using `eval set`
eval set -- "$args"
while (($#)); do
   case "$1" in
   -h) echo "help"; exit; ;;
   --file) file="$2"; shift; ;;
   --date) date="$2"; shift; ;;
   --) shift; break; ;;
   *) echo "Internal error - programmer made an error with this while or case" >&2; exit 1; ;;
   esac
   shift
done

echo file="$file" date="$date"
echo Rest of arguments: "$@"
```